# Array input in Elasticsearch Completion Suggester

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out why a scenario in ES doesn't seem to work for me. I have a pretty straightforward suggest mapping setup:

```
{
  "ding" : {
     "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
        "title" : { "type" : "string" },
        "test" : { "type" : "string" },
        "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "payloads": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
            }

        }
     }
}
```

And indexed the documents as such:

```
{
   "title": "Title",
   "name": "Name",
   "test": "Test",
   "suggest": {
      "input": [
         "Koolmees 21, Breda",
         "4822PP 21"
      ]
   }
}
```

The completion suggest works fine on:

```
{
    "ding" : {
      "text" : "Koo",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

But not on:

```
{
    "ding" : {
      "text" : "482",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because the input starts with a numeric character? I can't seem to figure it out :S

Answer (score 2):

The completion suggester uses the `simple` analyzer by default. If you use the `Analyze` API you can see it removes the numbers:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=simple&pretty=true' -d '4822PP 21'
```

returns

```
{
    "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "pp",
        "start_offset" : 4,
        "end_offset" : 6,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 1
   } ]
```

}

You may want to switch the auto completions to use the `Standard` analyzer.